# R remove latest week from time series

Tags: r

I have a time series dataset that contains a column `year`, `week` and a third numeric value.
From this dataset, I want to remove the last week from the last year as it is incomplete.

My attempt:

```
subset(data , year== max(as.numeric(as.character(data$year))) & week == max(data$week))
```

However, the problem with this code, is that it returns an empty dataframe, since the maximum week number, in the subset of the maximum year, does not exist.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: [here](https://pastebin.com/HnBpXgZt) is a link with a sample of the data I am using

Comment: Can you paste some sample data in the question, so I can provide a reproducible answer?

Comment: Yes, just did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `arrange` the data based on `year` and `week` and remove the `week` and `year` value which comes on the last line of the data.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(year, week) %>%
  filter(!(year == last(year) & week == last(week)))
```

Same logic in base R :

```
data <- type.convert(with(data, order(year, week)), as.is = TRUE)
subset(data, !(year == year[nrow(data)] & week == week[nrow(data)]))
```

Comment: Great solution. Can you elaborate on why ```type.convert(as.is = TRUE) ``` is required?

Comment: In an ideal case it should not be needed but I think OP's data has `year` and/or `week` data as character. `type.convert` changes it to numeric.